# Has George R. R. Martin ever mentioned plot elements from The Silmarillion in an interview?

Tags: george-r-r-martin

I was wondering if G. R. R. Martin has read *The Silmarillion*. Obviously, we can't know for sure, so my questions are these:

1. Has he ever said whether or not he's read it?
2. Has he ever mentioned plot elements from it in interviews?

Answer (score 5):

Certainly Martin is *aware* of Tolkien's Silmarillion (in terms of both content and concept) and references it multiple times in interviews, along with other of Tolkien's works, including his essays. I think it's fair to say that if he's not read it cover-to-cover then he's at least skimmed it.

> *Tolkien gave us all these histories all these appendices and
> genealogies and everything was was routed and it seemed as real as
> England or France or Germany when you when you read these things and
> since then that's become the style for epic fantasy. I see a lot of
> fantasy readers now expect they expect a fully real 'secondary world'
> as Tolkien called it and so certainly that's what I set out to
> creating in Westeros. Now some of this is a magician's trick [but] it really
> wasn't with Tolkien. You have to consider that Tolkien is, was a very
> unusual writer, I mean he was a linguist and a philosopher, spoke Old
> Norse and Old English, he was fascinated by myth you know he, the story
> was almost secondary to Tolkien. He spent years creating his
> Silmarillion and never published in his lifetime and the Lord of the
> Rings and The Hobbit were like the stories set in the world he created,
> but for him the world creation and the creation of languages was
> almost primary. If you look at it like an iceberg he, you know, they
> say that three-quarters of iceberg is hidden below thoughts below the
> surface that was certainly true [in his case]*

And

> My editors said, “This is going to ruin the entire concept of the
> book, we already spent the entire art budget, we can’t have art on
> every page of the book.” So we pulled out all the sidebars and I joked
> this was my Silmarillion — the GRRM-arillion — and we would publish it
> later. So The World of Ice and Fire was published close to its
> original conception…and Fire and Blood is the first time I’ve been
> able to present the material as it was originally written. Plus, I
> wrote additional material for it.
>
> <sub><sup>[George R.R. Martin gets candid about new book: 'What excites me most is I finished it'](https://ew.com/author-interviews/2018/11/19/george-rr-martin-interview/)</sup></sub>

etc

Comment: I haven't seen the interview yet, but in the quotes you gave, he doesn't mention ( in my opinion at least) anything concrete from the book. BTW, I extensively edited my question (although ultimately I ask the same things).

Comment: @Wade - Most authors don't talk about other author's works extensively. They're too busy talking about their own

Comment: Interestingly, the fact that GRRM refers to Tolkien's use of the term "Secondary world" would suggest that he's also read a few of Tolkien's essays found here; http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/The_Monsters_and_the_Critics

Comment: He talks a great deal in interviews about things Tolkien did in LotR which became tropes, e.g. the Dark Lord rising in the north, etc.